# Intent Not Received in Second Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a ListAdapter for a `RecyclerView` with an onClick method that gets the position of whichever item the user clicks, and that value is then passed to *ItemEditActivity*:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String stringo = dataList.get(position).id;

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ItemNumber", stringo);
                context.startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ItemEditActivity.class));

                Log.d(TAG, stringo + "");
            }
```

I then received the intent in *ItemEditActivity* with this code:

```
Intent Intent = getIntent();
                String intValue = Intent.getStringExtra("ItemNumber");
```

I log the *stringo* variable before it's passed and that's confirmed to have the correct value, but when attempting to log the *intValue* in my second activity, the value is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `context.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: You send wrong intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an Intent, but you are not using it.

```
// Your first Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemEditActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ItemNumber", stringo);

// Here, you are creating another Intent
context.startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ItemEditActivity.class));
```

You only need to pass the first Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemEditActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ItemNumber", stringo);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ClientList.class);
intent.putExtra("ItemNumber", stringo);
startActivity(intent);
```

Than in 2nd View you can try the below

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); //get the intent and data  passed
//next check that bundle is not null
if (bundle != null) {
    String intValue = bundle.getString("stringo"); 
    //try loging out the value
    Log.i("value", intValue);
}
```

This is how i have used the intents to pass data.